# SignalR Client doesn't receive signal in release mode (UWP)

Tags: c#, uwp, signalr, signalr.client

I use Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client 3.1.1 in my UWP application. My code works fine in debug mode, my app receive signal, but when i use release mode, my app doesn't receive signal.
I think compilator of VS doesn't including some methods or classes or something else. How i can resolve it? My code below:

```
var hubConnectionToWebService = new HubConnectionBuilder().WithUrl($"{Setting.Instance.UrlSignalR_WebService}").WithAutomaticReconnect(new RandomRetryPolicy()).Build();

hubConnectionToWebService.On<int, string>("ReceiveMessage", async (categoryID, tags) =>
                    {
                        Setting.Instance.CurrentCategoryID = categoryID;
                        await ReplacementBanners();
                    });

await ConnectWithRetryAsync(hubConnectionToWebService, tokenClosingClient);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved like that: added namespace to directives in Default.rd.xml

```
<Namespace Name="System.Text.Json" Dynamic="Required All" />
```